# Does there exist a non-zero matrix $B$ such that $AB = 0$, given $A$ to be non-singular?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am quite new to topics in linear algebra and try to verify my claim that there does not exist a non-zero matrix $B$ such that $AB=0$ given that $A$ is non-singular.

I browsed the forum for related question but could not find a convincing answer so far. The forum only investigated cases when $A$ it self has not full rank and then found that there indeed exists such a matrix $B$ that is non zero.

Can anybody help me to construct such a proof or provide me counter example that my claim is false?

Comment: Not duplicate, this one has $A$ non-singular (i.e., invertible), other question has $A$ non-invertible (i.e., non-singular). Closely related though

Comment: @MooS If it is a typo, it completely reverses the answer. Given that there are now two answers, reversing the "typo" is too late

Comment: Yes, maybe it wasn't a typo.

Comment: But at first glance, it is hard to believe someone would ask the question really this way.

Comment: thank you very much for pointing out the similar problem by Dietrich Burde. It really helped to deepen my understanding of the problem

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is invertible then from $AB=0$ you get $B=0$ by multiplying by $A^{-1}$ on the left on both sides.

Otherwise, consider the following example: $\overline{2}\in \mathbb{Z}_4$ is non-zero and it is a $1\times 1$ matrix. However
$$\overline{2}\cdot \overline{2}=\overline{4}=\overline{0}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If we have $AB=0$ and $A$ is not singular then:
$$
B=I\cdot B=(A^{-1}A)B=A^{-1}(AB)=A^{-1}\cdot 0=0
$$